# How to remove notepad from Files/open-with context menu?

Tags: files, menu, wine

Installing Wine brings notepad in the Open with - context menu of the file manager.

How to remove Notepad option from the context menu of the File manager?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted in [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/186501/47206):

*"wine-notepad creates a local mime association for text/plain and some other types in the file ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache; this effectively allows it as an alternative to anything gedit (or your default GUI editor) would otherwise open"*

What I did (as also said in a comment under that answer): **deleted altogether the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.** *"everything seems to default to my editor of choice"*.

Answer (score 1):

From the image you provide, it seems that the behavior you encounter is with text files (.txt).  IF it is such, then you can modify the list of "Open With" applications in the context menu like so:

In a terminal, go to: `/usr/share/applications` then do:

`sudo scratch-text-editor mimeinfo.cache`

There, find the line containing the string `text/plain`.  Change the list of associations to whatever you want (notepad should appear there so you just edit accordingly).  Save and exit.

Then:

`sudo scratch-text-editor defaults.list`  and repeat the operation from above.

Comment: The idea would be to remove notepad from any context menus. - Also: `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` and `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` do not contain `notepad` anywhere. This is different from just file association.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/186501/47206

Comment: the problem is ` ~/.local/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`.